# Weird kernel.shmax value

Tags: linux, rhel, kernel, kernel-parameters

I've noticed that `kernel.shmmax` value is set to oddly huge number on my RHEL 7 system.

```
# sysctl kernel.shmmax
kernel.shmmax = 18446744073692774399
```

1. Is it OK to have such a huge number set?
2. How can it affect the system?
3. What exactly that parameter means?

Some info about the system:

```
# cat /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.2 (Maipo)

# cat /proc/meminfo
MemTotal:        9037028 kB
MemFree:          175220 kB
MemAvailable:    2544492 kB
Buffers:               0 kB
Cached:          2716836 kB
SwapCached:        14908 kB
Active:          5749708 kB
Inactive:        2371364 kB
Active(anon):    4490064 kB
Inactive(anon):  1120848 kB
Active(file):    1259644 kB
Inactive(file):  1250516 kB
Unevictable:       10800 kB
Mlocked:           10796 kB
SwapTotal:       5242876 kB
SwapFree:        5143688 kB
Dirty:              9704 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:       5400268 kB
Mapped:           318000 kB
Shmem:            202700 kB
Slab:             379036 kB
SReclaimable:     169128 kB
SUnreclaim:       209908 kB
KernelStack:       34080 kB
PageTables:        46252 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:     9761388 kB
Committed_AS:    7599336 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:      181868 kB
VmallocChunk:   34359341052 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:   1861632 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
DirectMap4k:       92096 kB
DirectMap2M:     9345024 kB
```

```
# uname -a
Linux hostname 3.10.0-693.21.1.el7.AV1.x86_64 #1 SMP Thursday April 5, 2018 09:26:08 MDT x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Well, `kernel.shmall` parameter has the same value.

```
$ sysctl -a | grep shm
kernel.shmall = 18446744073692774399
kernel.shmmax = 18446744073692774399
kernel.shmmni = 4096
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysctl/kernel.txt

Comment: @mkmayank, thank you. Now it is clear about its origination. But can such huge value affect system's performance?
I have another VM with RHEL6.5. On that machine `kernel.shmmax = 33554432`. Not sure that I've set that value manually somewhere...